# Android NDK RegisterNatives more full example

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm try to make Android Native C++ project in Android Studio 2020.3.1.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#native_libraries) and [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/improvements#faster-native-methods) provided common tips for using RegisterNatives in JNI_OnLoad. But in this examples i can't understand what is ***nativeFoo*** and ***nativeBar*** ? These are methods or functions of c++ code? And what is doing MyClass in example ? I want more full and clear code example for Android NDK C++ native. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/android/ndk-samples

Comment: For 99% of use cases, you can rely on the automatic mapping of C++ functions to Java native methods. See [Resolving Native Method Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp679).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going backwards from the `RegisterNatives` call in the first link, it hooks up native C++ methods to the following Java class:

```
package com.example.app.package;

class MyClass {
    public native void nativeFoo();
    public native bool nativeBar(String, int);
}
```

and it expects that you defined the following C++ functions earlier:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL nativeFoo(JNIEnv *env, jobject object) { ... }
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL nativeBar(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jstring a, jint b) { ... }
```

Comment: One moment, what about once called at lib load functions in OnLoad ?